# Как регулировать хитбокс в Unity 2D?

Tags: unity3d

C помощью какого компонента можно регулировать хитбокс у объекта в Unity 2D?

Comment: Жмакни по кнопке `Add Component` и вбей в строку поиска `collider2d`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Сначала создай сам объект

[image]

Затем выбери Add component, Physics2D

[image]

Там есть много разных, выбирай нужный

Если же хочешь поменять размер, то это есть в самом компоненте, а если через скрипт, то обращайся так:

```
"object".GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().size
```